# Issue in binding json value to html in angular 2

Tags: html, json, angular

I am getting json object from API, I wanted to bind that JSON object value to my html.
Following is json object

```
[
{
    "cat_name": "FAMILY TIME",
    "id": 9,
    "blog_data": [
        {
            "ID": 46,
            "post_author": "1",
            "post_date": "2017-07-17 10:43:55",
            "post_date_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:43:55",
            "post_content": "this is second one",
            "post_title": "second one",
            "post_excerpt": "",
            "post_status": "publish",
            "comment_status": "open",
            "ping_status": "open",
            "post_password": "",
            "post_name": "second-one",
            "to_ping": "",
            "pinged": "",
            "post_modified": "2017-07-17 10:57:06",
            "post_modified_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:57:06",
            "post_content_filtered": "",
            "post_parent": 0,
            "guid": "",
            "menu_order": 0,
            "post_type": "post",
            "post_mime_type": "",
            "comment_count": "0",
            "filter": "raw"
        }
    ],
    "imageurl": "/wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg"
},
{
    "cat_name": "FOODIE",
    "id": 7,
    "blog_data": [
        {
            "ID": 48,
            "post_author": "1",
            "post_date": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
            "post_date_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
            "post_content": "this is foodie in",
            "post_title": "check one foodie",
            "post_excerpt": "",
            "post_status": "publish",
            "comment_status": "open",
            "ping_status": "open",
            "post_password": "",
            "post_name": "check-one-foodie",
            "to_ping": "",
            "pinged": "",
            "post_modified": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
            "post_modified_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
            "post_content_filtered": "",
            "post_parent": 0,
            "guid": "",
            "menu_order": 0,
            "post_type": "post",
            "post_mime_type": "",
            "comment_count": "0",
            "filter": "raw"
        }
    ],
    "imageurl": "/wp-content/country-guide1.jpg"
}]
```

Typescript code as follows

```
CategoryBlogHomePage() {
    var self = this;
    var timez = '';

    self.blogapi.CategoryBlogHomePage().subscribe(
        x => {
            this.BlogListByCat = x;

            console.log(this.BlogListByCat);
        });
}
```

And my html is as follows

```
 <a *ngFor="let blogList of BlogListByCat ; let i = index" class="featured-story cover-bg post{{i}}" href="#"   style="background-image: url('http://my.blog.net{{blogList.imageurl}}');">
                    <div class="post-details">
                        <span class="post-category hardscience-cat">{{blogList.cat_name}}  </span>
                        <h3 class="featured-story-title">{{blogList.blog_data.post_title}} </h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

My problem is i am not able to bind image and blog_data values.
Property imageurl returns /wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg which i wanted to append with the domain but it is not showing anything and when i put it manually for eg.http://my.blog.net/wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg it works so the problem is something with the formatting in html. Also i wanted to show post_title property of blog_data for this i have written {{blogList.blog_data.post_title}} which is not working.
plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this.

```
 <div class="post-details">
    <span class="post-category hardscience-cat">{{blogList.cat_name}}  </span>
   <h3 class="featured-story-title">{{blogList.blog_data[0].post_title}} </h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks that worked. Now the only problem is image. Any idea for tha?

Comment: if you get data by using [0]. then  why you need nested ngFor?

Comment: @C.jacking check your image url. and bind it in nghrf on img tag

Comment: @RameshRajendran when i put it manually for eg. http://my.blog.net/wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg it works .

Comment: @C.jacking I think your imageurl should be `./wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg`

Comment: I tried  style="background-image: url('.{{blogList.imageurl}}');" but nothing happened.

Comment: for display image use this `<img [src]="blogList.imageurl">`

Comment: when i use <img [src]="blogList.imageurl"> it gives me this path /wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg which again does not work. i might need to append my domain to it.so i did something <img [src]="http://my.blog.net"+blogList.imageurl> but nothing worked

Comment: This worked for me [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(http://my.blog.net' + blogList.imageurl + ')'}" Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

instead of  {{blogList.blog_data.post_title}} and {{blogList.imageurl}}, use following lines which is there in console.log

```
var blogList = [
    {
        "cat_name": "FAMILY TIME",
        "id": 9,
        "blog_data": [
            {
                "ID": 46,
                "post_author": "1",
                "post_date": "2017-07-17 10:43:55",
                "post_date_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:43:55",
                "post_content": "this is second one",
                "post_title": "second one",
                "post_excerpt": "",
                "post_status": "publish",
                "comment_status": "open",
                "ping_status": "open",
                "post_password": "",
                "post_name": "second-one",
                "to_ping": "",
                "pinged": "",
                "post_modified": "2017-07-17 10:57:06",
                "post_modified_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:57:06",
                "post_content_filtered": "",
                "post_parent": 0,
                "guid": "",
                "menu_order": 0,
                "post_type": "post",
                "post_mime_type": "",
                "comment_count": "0",
                "filter": "raw"
            }
        ],
        "imageurl": "/wp-content/baanner-loan.jpg"
    },
    {
        "cat_name": "FOODIE",
        "id": 7,
        "blog_data": [
            {
                "ID": 48,
                "post_author": "1",
                "post_date": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
                "post_date_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
                "post_content": "this is foodie in",
                "post_title": "check one foodie",
                "post_excerpt": "",
                "post_status": "publish",
                "comment_status": "open",
                "ping_status": "open",
                "post_password": "",
                "post_name": "check-one-foodie",
                "to_ping": "",
                "pinged": "",
                "post_modified": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
                "post_modified_gmt": "2017-07-17 10:45:44",
                "post_content_filtered": "",
                "post_parent": 0,
                "guid": "",
                "menu_order": 0,
                "post_type": "post",
                "post_mime_type": "",
                "comment_count": "0",
                "filter": "raw"
            }
        ],
        "imageurl": "/wp-content/country-guide1.jpg"
    }]


    console.log(blogList[0].imageurl)
    console.log(blogList[1].imageurl)
    console.log(blogList[0].blog_data[0].post_title)
    console.log(blogList[1].blog_data[0].post_title)
```

Comment: for image it showing error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageurl' of undefined when i use blogList[0].imageurl